# Powershell Connect to VSO

Tags: powershell, authentication, tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to use Powershell to connect to VSO. Here is my code:

```
$tfsServer = New-Object System.Uri("the server is here")
$creds = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$tfsCollection = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection($tfsServer,$creds)
$tfsCollection.Authenticate()
```

When it reaches the Authenticate line, it pops up a box for me to enter my credentials. I need it to not pop up this box, as this script will be scheduled, and I can't keep entering the credentials. How can I pass the current user's credentials to the TFS object?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

First, run this command which will prompt you once for your password, and then save it in an encrypted format.

```
read-host -prompt Password -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file .\ps-password.pwd -ErrorAction Stop
```

Change the $username variable

```
$Username = 'jdoe'

$Password = Get-Content ".\ps-password.pwd" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$creds = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$Password
$tfsServer = New-Object System.Uri("the server is here")
$tfsCollection = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection($tfsServer,$creds)
$tfsCollection.Authenticate()
```

Comment: that just passes credentials for "jdoe" to TFS. i want it to get the currently logged in user, whomever the script is running as.

Comment: $Username = $env:USERNAME

Comment: Or if you need domain included: $Username = $env:USERDOMAIN + '\' + $env:USERNAME

Comment: But then how would it know which password file to use?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [constructor that just takes a URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731786.aspx). It will default to using the credentials of the current user.

Comment: It still pops up a window asking me to log in.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to Visual Studio Online, you have to follow the instructions at [Buck's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2013/01/07/how-to-connect-to-tf-service-without-a-prompt-for-liveid-credentials.aspx). Shortly:

1. enable alternate credentials on the VSO account
2. set alternate user and password
3. use code similar to the following

> ```
> $tfsServer = New-Object System.Uri("the server is here")
> $netCred = New-Object NetworkCredential("alternate_user","alternate_password")
> $basicCred = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.BasicAuthCredential($netCred)
> $tfsCred = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsClientCredentials($basicCred)
> $tfsCred.AllowInteractive = $false
> $tfsCollection = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection($tfsServer,$tfsCred)
> $tfsCollection.EnsureAuthenticated()
> ```

I know no way of using current process credentials with VSO, but you must explicitly pass them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [EnsureAuthenticated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.tfsconnection.ensureauthenticated.aspx) and do not specify credentials.

```
$tfsCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection("the server is here")
$tfsCollection.EnsureAuthenticated()
```

This way it will use the account running the process.

Comment: I assumed you work with TFS on-premises and IE configuration (which is shared with .Net) is correct -- "Automatic logon" for the Zone.
It target TFS is on another domain/workgroup, you must use the Credential Manager.

Comment: Ah I think therein lies my issue. I'm not using TFS on-premesis, i'm using TFS online (server.visualstudio.com). I think it's an issue with the way TFS online does authentication.